# How to calculate the uncertainty of a parameter when using a cost function other than the least squares?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, standard-deviation, monte-carlo, nonlinear-regression

**Context:**

Given some measurements $y_i$ associated with the independent variable $x$ and uncertainties $\sigma_i$ and, on the other hand, a model $f(x;\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a free parameter (which does not have to be linear), then one can find the most likely $\theta$ that reproduces the data by minimizing what I refer to as a cost function

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(y_i-f(x_i;\theta))^2}{\sigma_i^2}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

One way to do the minimization is to sample the whole parameter space of $\theta$ and then search for the minimum $\chi_{\rm min}^2$. If I now want to estimate the 1-$\sigma$ uncertainty for $\theta$ <sup>1</sup>, I can plot the whole parameter space of $\theta$ versus the PDF derived from equation (\ref{1}), which is $\exp(-0.5\chi^2)$ assuming Gaussian errors, and collect the 68% of the probability around $\chi_{\rm min}^2$ to find the interval $\theta_1<\theta_2$ that represent the sought uncertainty.

**My question:**

How do I calculate the uncertainty for $\theta$ when the function to minimize is different from equation (\ref{1})?

For example, if equation (\ref{1}) is slightly modified and replaced with

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^N w_1 w_2\frac{(y_i-f(x_i;\theta))^2}{\sigma_i^2}\tag{2}\label{2}$$

where $w_1$ is **a weight that depends on the measurements** and $w_2$ is **a weight that depends on the parameter $\theta$**. I still can find the most likely $\theta$ that reproduces the data through minimizing equation (\ref{2}) by sampling the whole parameter space of $\theta$ and then searching for the minimum $S_{\rm min}$. However, I can no longer estimate the 1-$\sigma$ uncertainty for $\theta$ by plotting the whole parameter space of $\theta$ versus the PDF because the PDF is no longer $\exp(-0.5\chi^2)$.

**Footnotes:**

1. Which I may incorrectly be referring to as "confidence interval".

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using a bootstrap estimate?

Comment: @Sergio, effectively, I can get an error for Theta using a bootstrap estimate. However, one advantage of computing the cost function for the entire parameter space of Theta is that I can later draw contour plots for a certain value of the cost function. If Theta is two parameters instead of one, those contours are likely to be ellipses. If I were to get an error for Theta1 and Theta2 using a bootstrap estimate, I would end up with rectangular contours. What I am then looking for is a value for the cost function at which contours represent more or less the uncertainty of one standard deviation.

Comment: What does $\sigma_i$ mean? My point is that one doesn't have an estimate for variance until one finds the minimum of the OLS norm. So, I am missing some explanation for why one is using a variance that is not a variance of minimum error.

Comment: Could you bootstrap?

Comment: If your cost function can be interpreted as a negative log-likelihood value, then a common thing to do is to use the Fisher Information matrix. The idea is basically to approximate the loss function near the minimum with a Gaussian pdf, and then compute the variance of that approximating Gaussian.

Comment: Doesn't your whole contour shift/distort to all directions based on the sample you have? For example, for every round of bootstrap the whole contour will be a bit different. I would consider the amount of change as uncertainty, which is rather different from the gradient or convexity of the contour that impacts your convergent rate. Sigma here doesn't look like a variance either way looking at the definition only.